# How to check if there are values in a table in the database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a project where in I want to verify if there is a data that has been inserted in a table by a certain user and display it if there's any. I'm fairly new to CodeIgniter and I'm unsure of how to display all the lists that has been by a certain user if it is logged in.

This is what I have in my model so far:

```
 public function get_all_lists($user_id){
            $this->db->where('list_creator_id', $user_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('lists');

            return $query->result();    
        }
```

This is what I have on my view:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_controllers/lists/create" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                    Create a List
                </a>
                <h3 align="center">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_controllers/lists/display/<?php echo $list->id;?>">
                        <?php echo $list->list_name; ?>
                    </a>            
                </h3>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is what I have on my controller:

```
public function index(){
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->load->model('project_models/lists_model');

        $data['lists'] = $this->lists_model->get_all_lists($user_id);

        $data['main_view'] = "project_views/lists/index";

        $this->load->view('project_views/layouts/main', $data);
    }
```

My goal here is to display all the lists that has been created by a certain user if it is logged in. If the user has been logged in and has not created any list, I want a message that says, **"You don't have created any lists yet"**.

Comment: $query->num_rows(); gives the number of rows returned by the query. You can use it like this in your Model -> if($query->num_rows > 0){ return $query->result(); } return false; and handle it appropriately as per your requirement and design in your Controller.

Comment: Thanks for that, @VenkatD I got that to work and display it in my controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `num_rows()` to return either the object or false.

```
public function get_all_lists($user_id){
            $this->db->where('list_creator_id', $user_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('lists');
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->result(); 
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Usage:

```
if ($lists) {
    foreach(...) {

    }
} else {
    echo 'no rows';
}
```